# Find the Two Sentences

Tags: word-property

## Introduction

This puzzle has 2 Parts. The goal of each Part is to fill in the blanks for that Part's sentence. Once that is completed, you have finished the Part. Once you have completed both Parts, you have completed the puzzle.

First, solve each Section in a Part. Each Section is in a table. The first row in each Section's table is the summary row for that Section. Skip that first row when you start a Section. When you complete a Section, use that Section's information to fill in that top row.

After solving one or two rows in a Section, you will realize that each pair of words in a row have a special relationship that will hold true for all rows in all Sections in both Parts. That property is a huge clue and confirmation.

When all of the Sections in a Part are complete, fill in that Part's sentence by choosing the correct word from the word pair in the top row of each Part. They are in order, which means that the first word in a Part sentence is one of the two words in row 1 of Section 1, the second word in a Part sentence is one of the two words in row 1 of Section 2, etc.

*Requesting No Partial Answers - Post an answer only if you have found all of the sentences and either all of the words or all of the words except one.*

Please add any relevant tags. I am not sure how to tag this one.

## Part 1 Sentence

`I [_ _] [_ _ _ _ _] [_ _ _] [_ _ _] [_ _ _ _] to a [_ _ _] I [_ _ _ _] at the [_ _ _ _].`

### Section 1 of 8

| -------- Word 1 -------- | -------- Word 2 -------- | Sentence Using Both Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ _` | `_ _` | **`_ [_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _] [_ _ _ _ _ _].`** |
| `_ ▯ _` | `_ ▯ ▯` | The room was [mostly unlit] in [central] winter. |
| `_ ▯ _ ▯ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ ▯ _ _ _ _` | She [again crochets] the socks the [bugger] damaged. |
| `_ _ _ ▯ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ _ _` | The [hunter of wolves] waits for the water to [run again]. |
| `▯ _ _` | `_ ▯ _` | They [chatter] about how much they [spend] for rent. |
| `_ _ _ ▯` | `_ ▯ _ _` | He heard the [booms] of drums as he cleaned the [soot] in the chimney. |
| `_ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _` | The limes [decay] on the [craggy hill]. |
| `_ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _` | [The female not talking or hearing] was annoyed by the Canadian's many "[yeses]". |
| `_ _ _ _` | `_ _ ▯ _` | The [preparedness] of the [gunman] was outstanding. |

### Section 2 of 8

| ------ Word 1 ------ | ------ Word 2 ------ | Sentence Using Both Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ _ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ _` | **`_ _ _ _ _ [_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _] _ _ [_ _ _ _ _].`** |
| `_ ▯ _ _ _ _` | `▯ _ ▯ _ _ _` | The [students] who don't make a single [error] win the game. |
| `_ _ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _ ▯` | The [pungent odor] of the dumpster attracted the [small dipteran fly]. |
| `_ _ _ _ _ ▯` | `_ _ _ ▯ _ ▯` | The [plunderer] expected that the owner would [get new tools for] the shop. |
| `_ _ ▯` | `_ ▯ _` | The [smooth, slimy-skinned snakelike fish] hid in the [protecting shelter] of the coral. |
| `▯ _ _ _` | `▯ _ _ _` | A dog [yelps] as the doctors [remove the ovaries and uterus of] our cat. |
| `_ _ ▯ _ _ _` | `▯ _ _ _ _ ▯` | Men of different noble [lineages] repaired the [mast-to-peak spars] on their boats. |
| `_ _ ▯ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ _` | He [skillfully breaks off pieces] of the flint while we [smack] our child's bottom for disobedience. |
| `_ _ ▯ _` | `_ ▯ _ _` | Will you let a man [have life] who is [seeking to harm others for no reason]? |
| `_ _ _` | `▯ _ _` | The pilot's [method] is to use [the pointing of a planes nose left or right]. |

### Section 3 of 8

| -------- Word 1 -------- | -------- Word 2 -------- | Sentence Using Both Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ _ _` | `_ _ _` | **`_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ [_ X _ _ _ _] _ _ _ [_ _ _ _].`** |
| `▯ _ _ _` | `_ _ ▯ _` | I [drive away] a fly while the crowd [aahs] at the magic trick. |
| `_ _ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ ▯ _ ▯` | They [put laces in] their boots and decorated them with a [design made to be transferred]. |
| `_ _ _ ▯ _ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _ ▯ _ _ _` | [The man tending the entrance] made us wear a [sticker with our name on it]. |
| `_ _ _ ▯` | `_ _ ▯ ▯` | I [praise] the U.S. and the U.K. for allowing [double] citizenship. |
| `_ _ ▯` | `_ ▯ _` | She put the [jelly-like substance] on her left [lower limb]. |
| `_ _ ▯ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _ ▯` | The [walker with consistently-sized steps] just wanted a [concise summary]. |
| `▯ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ ▯` | I was [ticked] off that the bugspray with [a colorless oily liquid insect repellent] didn't work. |
| `▯ _` | `▯ _` | [The male neither speaking nor listening] sought confirmation by appending the word "[right]". |
| `▯ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _` | His eyes will [wink in surprise] at the [bill]. |
| `_ ▯` | `_ _` | I said "[how surprising]", and they responded "[how funny]"! |

### Section 4 of 8

| ------ Word 1 ------ | ------ Word 2 ------ | Sentence Using Both Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ _ _` | `_ _ _` | **`_ [_ _ _ H _] _ _ _ _ [_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _].`** |
| `_ ▯ _ _` | `_ ▯ ▯ _` | Spring is the [duration] in which many flowers [send out] pleasing aromas. |
| `_ _ ▯` | `_ _ ▯` | The gangster put a [plastic identification slip] on his [handgun]. |
| `_ ▯ _ ▯ ▯` | `_ ▯ ▯ _ _` | When she [retook] the test, she brought a [stun gun]. |
| `▯ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _` | The scandal didn't [defile] her because she would not [give away] the main players. |
| `_ _ ▯ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ _` | He [straightforwardly dealt with] the day, having [coffee with little caffeine]. |
| `_ _ _` | `_ _ ▯` | When asked if I liked the [clothing border doubled back and stitched down], I replied, "[so-so]". |
| `_ _` | `_ ▯` | [Hey], I yelled "[yikes]" in frustration. |
| `▯ ▯ ▯ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _ _ _` | The [inner tube rider] could not [refute] his friend's claims. |
| `_ ▯ _` | `_ _ _` | Does [the supreme creator being] have a [barking domesticated carnivorous mammal]? |
| `_ ▯ _` | `_ _ ▯` | I ate a [large sandwich on a split roll] on the [large passenger vehicle]. |
| `▯ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ ▯ _` | He left the [partitioned part of the inside of the building] to [anchor] the boat. |
| `_ _ ▯` | `_ _ _` | He would love to [catch] the [exceptionally attractive woman]. |

### Section 5 of 8

| ------ Word 1 ------ | ------ Word 2 ------ | Sentence Using Both Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _` | **`I [_ _ _ _ _] _ _ _ _ _ _ _ [_ _ Y _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _].`** |
| `▯ _ _` | `▯ _ _` | My [male sibling] admired the [spherical celestial object]. |
| `_ ▯ _ ▯` | `_ ▯ ▯ _` | Show me your new [skin art] [immediately]! |
| `▯ _ _ _` | `_ _ ▯ _` | It's a [timely benefit] to the [one who is new to a particular activity]. |
| `_ ▯ _` | `_ _ ▯` | When I [pull] the rope in tug of war, my [belly] jiggles. |
| `_ _` | `▯ _` | I hesitated with "[uh]" when she asked me about the etymology of [the 12th Greek letter]. |
| `_ _ _ ▯` | `_ _ _ ▯` | They [waver] as the boat [moves side-to-side]. |
| `▯ _ ▯ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _ _` | The [tile installer] [again ignited] the wick. |
| `_ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ _ ▯` | The men will [whip] you for interrupting their round of [sinking balls into 18 holes using clubs]. |
| `_ _ _ ▯ ▯` | `▯ ▯ ▯ _ _` | The nylon [band] held all the small [components]. |
| `_ ▯ _ _` | `▯ _ _ _` | We [slump] over after eating a [garden herb with mildly pungent succulent leaves and a thick stalk]. |

### Section 6 of 8

| ------ Word 1 ------ | ------ Word 2 ------ | Sentence Using Both Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ _ _` | `_ _ _` | **`_ [_ _ _ _] _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ [_ _ _ _] _ _ H _ _ _.`** |
| `_ ▯ _ ▯` | `_ ▯ _ _` | The [women] sanded the [metal dross] on the fence. |
| `_ _ ▯ ▯` | `▯ ▯ _ _` | Two rivers [stream] by as they [greedily devour] their meal. |
| `_ _ ▯ _ _` | `_ _ _ ▯ ▯` | The [appellation giver] will [supply replacement workers for] the abandoned positions. |
| `_ _ ▯` | `_ ▯ _` | He will [lower and raise his head quickly] in approval when I [put on] my new dress! |
| `_ _ _ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _ _ ▯` | He [axes] those who use fonts without a [short line on the end of each letter stroke]. |
| `_ _ ▯ ▯ _ _` | `_ _ ▯ _ _ _` | The automated [device that dials] made our calls while we [again put down] the track. |
| `▯ _ _` | `_ _ _` | My [friend] will [provide the Spanish dialogue for] the English movie. |
| `_ ▯ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ ▯ _ ▯` | They wore [the fabric of jeans] when they [dug into the earth]. |

### Section 7 of 8

| ------ Word 1 ------ | ------ Word 2 ------ | Sentence Using Both Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _` | **`_ _ _ [_ _ _ _ _] [_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _] _ H _ _ _ _ _.`** |
| `_ ▯ ▯ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _ _` | He heard the [combination of nine voices] as he cut the [wood projection used for a joint]. |
| `_ _ ▯ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _ ▯` | The number of deer in the [granular snow fields] was [the only prime number preceding a cube]. |
| `_ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ ▯ ▯` | A Roman believer in [God] [brought an action against] a small group of non-believers. |
| `_ _ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _ _` | The prophets of [inevitable destruction] are [state of mind] killers. |
| `_ ▯ _` | `_ _ ▯` | [Clip] the flowers and [tack] your hours on the board. |
| `▯ _ _ _ ▯` | `_ ▯ _ _ _` | The [court's decision] was about the naming of a [moon's highland area]. |
| `▯ _ _ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ ▯ _ ▯ _` | It [showers frozen rain] but he [emboldens] himself to face to cold. |
| `_ ▯ _ _` | `▯ _ _ ▯` | Both [ends] of the [slender, meat-cooking rod] were sharp. |

### Section 8 of 8

| ------ Word 1 ------ | ------ Word 2 ------ | Sentence Using Both Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _` | **`_ _ _ [_ _ _ _ _ _ _] _ _ _ _ _ _ _ Y _ [_ _ _ _ _ _].`** |
| `_ _ _` | `▯ _ _` | I have the moves down [perfectly] when my comrades [lightly strike] the window. |
| `▯ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _` | When the shot completely missed the [the rim of a basketball goal], I said, "[boo]!" |
| `▯ _ _ _` | `▯ _ _ _` | We [revise] our video of the [rising and falling of the ocean surface]. |
| `▯ _ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _` | The [crucifix symbolizing Jesus's cross] hung over the [portal]. |
| `_ _ _ _ ▯` | `▯ _ _ ▯ _` | We [take intense satisfaction] at the simplicity and utility of the [bar used for prying]. |
| `_ _ _ ▯` | `_ _ _ _` | My horse pulled the [strong wagon] across the [grounds of the building]. |
| `▯ ▯ _ ▯` | `▯ _ _ _` | The camera [moves horizontally] when I [make a popping noise with my fingers]. |
| `_ _ _ ▯ _` | `▯ _ ▯ _ _` | We [rode an inflated tube] down the river for our [first appearance] . |
| `_ ▯ _` | `▯ ▯ ▯` | The [male sheep] did [ruin the perfection of] the new Ferrari by walking on it. |
| `_ _ _ ▯ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _ _ ▯` | We [fiddle] with yarn as we [again knit] the unraveled sweaters. |

---

## Part 2 Sentence

`With the [_ _ _ _ _] [_ _], the [_ _ _ _ _] [_ _ _] [_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _], but now he [_ _ _ _ _] [_ _ _ _] of tops for the [_ _ _ _ _ _].`

### Section 1 of 8

| -------- Word 1 -------- | -------- Word 2 -------- | Sentence Using Both Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ _ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ _` | **`_ [_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _] _ _ _ _ [_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _] _ H _ _ _ _ _.`** |
| `_ ▯ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _` | The [large rodents] were warmed by the [shining, ball-shaped gaseous celestial body]. |
| `_ _ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ ▯ ▯ _` | She will [resign] office if her progress is [monitored for duration]. |
| `_ _ _ _` | `▯ _ _ _` | Despite his high [degree of excellence], he couldn't saw through the huge [knot] in the log. |
| `_ _ _ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ _ _ _ _` | The [silk-producing arachnid] [abruptly lowers again] for repairs. |
| `_ _ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _ _` | In the [strongest and securest part of a medieval castle], I [peer] out of a crack . |
| `_ _ _ ▯` | `_ _ _ _` | Shrek is an [ugly giant of fairy tales]; [therefore], people fear him. |
| `▯ _ _` | `▯ _ _` | Eating the [uncooked] oysters caused [conflict] in his gut. |
| `_ _ ▯ ▯` | `▯ _ _ _` | The word [banister] has five letters, said the [fibber]. |
| `_ ▯ ▯ _ ▯` | `_ ▯ _ ▯ _` | When he [sees] the hunter, the deer [halts] . |
| `_ ▯ _ _` | `_ _ _ ▯` | The [sushi wrap] was kept in a bowl made of [a magnetic heavy metallic element]. |
| `_ ▯ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _` | All the [domesticated animals kept for pleasure] [tread] in the mud. |
| `_ ▯ ▯ ▯ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _ _ _` | The height of the [ice pinnacles] [frightens] me away. |
| `_ _ _` | `_ ▯ _` | She found a [novel] technique for [abnormal skin growth] removal. |

### Section 2 of 8

| ------ Word 1 ------ | ------ Word 2 ------ | Sentence Using Both Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ _` | `_ _` | **`_ _ _ [_ _ _ _ _] _ X _ _ _ _ [_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _] _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _.`** |
| `_ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ ▯ _` | Use the numbers [oriented] diagonally on the [gauge]. |
| `_ _ ▯` | `_ _ _` | I got [sweetened insoluble plastic material] on the bottom of my [cylindrical drinking cup]. |
| `_ _ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ ▯ _` | She [barks] at me as I measure the [distances between the points]. |
| `_ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _` | For an experienced worker, it's [in no way] a [lot] of work. |
| `_ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _` | She cleaned the [broad, shallow cooking container] and decided to [sleep briefly]. |
| `_ ▯ ▯ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _ ▯` | Nothing could [drive away] the [person shunned for moral or social reasons]. |
| `▯ _ _ _ ▯` | `_ ▯ _ _ _` | The [drunk] does [place into new pots] the herbs. |
| `▯ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _` | He held the slippery [pike-like fish with elongated body and jaws] with a [waste piece of cloth]. |
| `▯ _ _ ▯ _ _` | `_ _ _ ▯ _ _` | A [rejecter] of the fact that Earth is globe-shaped won't be [controlled] by logic and evidence. |
| `_ _ _ ▯` | `_ ▯ ▯ _` | The birds have [voiced musical tones] their songs but the [wildebeests] still sleep. |
| `_ _ _ ▯` | `_ ▯ _ _` | The [wrongful act for which relief can be granted] is that horses did [jog] on my feet! |
| `_ ▯ _` | `▯ ▯ _` | He put the [louse egg] in the [metal container]. |
| `_ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _` | His [male child] supported it, but the bill got enough [negative votes] to kill it. |

### Section 3 of 8

| -------- Word 1 -------- | -------- Word 2 -------- | Sentence Using Both Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ _ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ _` | **`_ H _ [_ _ _ _] _ _ _ _ _ [_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _].`** |
| `_ ▯ _ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ _ _` | The [stope drillman] [again places in pots] the flowers. |
| `_ _ _ _ _ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _ _ _ _` | He was [verbally abused] when he didn't [convey] the mail on time. |
| `_ _ _ ▯` | `_ _ _ _` | Their [light sleeps] sometimes [last] hours. |
| `_ _ _` | `_ _ ▯` | We [catch] violators of a [legal prohibition]. |
| `_ _ ▯ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ _` | She [coils] the thread around the [rimmed plastic cylinder]. |
| `_ _ _ _` | `▯ _ _ _` | The [small rounded handle] might [hit] him on the head. |
| `_ _ _ _ ▯` | `_ ▯ _ _ _` | Maybe the [serpent] also [dwelled] in the Garden of Eden. |
| `▯ _ ▯ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ _` | The [boats] looked [smooth and glossy, as if polished]. |
| `_ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ ▯` | What if dogs could [switch] [feet] with bears? |
| `_ ▯ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ ▯ _ _` | They [leave quickly] because the brandy comes from the [residues] of both grapes and currants. |
| `▯ _ _` | `_ ▯ _` | At the [summit] of the mountain, they smoked [marijuana]. |
| `_ _ _ _ _ _` | `_ _ ▯ _ _ _` | The [rimmed plastic cylinders] are on the [single-masted, fore-and-aft-rigged sailboats]. |
| `_ _ _ ▯` | `_ _ _ ▯` | The wheels [rotate] as he [cuts] the hedges. |

### Section 4 of 8

| ------ Word 1 ------ | ------ Word 2 ------ | Sentence Using Both Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ _ _` | `_ _ _` | **`_ Y [C _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _] [_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _] _ H _ _ _.`** |
| `_ _ _` | `_ _ ▯` | She was the [angry] [dike] builder. |
| `_ ▯ ▯ _` | `_ ▯ _ _` | No [exceptions] about it- you must show the [part of the ticket you retained]. |
| `_ ▯ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _` | They [ring] the tiny bell while wearing [interlaced, connected-loop yarn fabric] socks. |
| `▯ _ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _` | The sound of the [firearms] made the [adult male deer] run. |
| `_ ▯ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _ _` | The pirate used only one [device] to get the [booty]. |
| `_ ▯ _ _` | `▯ _ _ _` | Our [firearms] are [fitting closely and comfortably] in their cases. |
| `_ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _` | We [got married] in [moisture]. |
| `_ _ ▯` | `_ _ ▯` | She ate [cereal grain] cookies and pondered the [unconditional source and guiding principle of all reality]. |
| `_ _ _` | `▯ _ _` | They [talk rapidly] while shopping for [a flexible container used for carrying]. |
| `▯ _` | `_ _` | She often used "[uh]" when hesitating, and directed her responses with "[in regard to]". |
| `_ _ _ ▯` | `_ _ _ _` | If the dog [micturates] inside, the urine will [exude] into the carpet. |
| `_ _ _ _` | `_ _ ▯ _` | The [composer of poetry about heroes] had a [dull and monotonous] life. |
| `_ _ ▯ _ _` | `_ _ _ ▯ _` | The [young child] made a fort with two [tarpaulins]. |

### Section 5 of 8

| -------- Word 1 -------- | -------- Word 2 -------- | Sentence Using Both Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _` | **`_ H _ _ H _ _ [_ _ _ H _ _ _ _ _ _] [_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _].`** |
| `_ _ ▯` | `_ _ _` | Avoiding the [hole in the ground] was the first [pointer]. |
| `_ ▯ _ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ ▯ ▯ _` | He [summarizes] the details of each [piece used to maintain a certain amount of space]. |
| `_ _ ▯ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _ _` | She [again fed] the cat and didn't [delay] the task. |
| `▯ _ _ _` | `_ ▯ ▯ _` | She [charts] the area codes from which most [unsolicited mass text messages] are sent. |
| `▯ _ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _` | She does [clip] a coupon for a set of [metal fasteners]. |
| `_ _ _ _` | `▯ _ _ _` | The [klutz] accidentally [shocks] himself with the taser. |
| `_ ▯ _ _` | `▯ _ _ ▯` | Don Day sowed [ripened ovules of plants] in the shape of [his initials]. |
| `▯ _` | `▯ _` | [My group and I] said "[yuck]!" to the rotten fish smell. |
| `_ ▯ _ ▯ _` | `_ ▯ _ _ _` | He knew the [details] about his [spirited horse]. |
| `_ ▯ _` | `_ _ _` | These [constitute the same class as] the only songs of that [time period]. |
| `_ _ _ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _ _` | He said the [relatively light and clear beer type] was [fit for royalty]. |
| `_ ▯ _` | `_ _ _` | His takes the [responsibility] for being two under [the score standard] on hole six. |
| `_ _ ▯ _` | `▯ _ _ _` | The [toddlers] saw the mule deer [pronk] when the panther gave chase. |

### Section 6 of 8

| --------- Word 1 --------- | --------- Word 2 --------- | Sentence Using Both Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ _ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ _` | **`_ _ [_ _ _ _ _ _] _ H _ _ _ _ [_ H _ _ _ _].`** |
| `_ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ _ _` | The child [urinated] in the pool's [not-so-shallow] end. |
| `_ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ ▯` | I will [pencil] a masterpiece and [protect] it from the elements. |
| `_ _ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ _ _ _` | He [pillages] the store and makes off with a [four-legged seat with no back or arms]. |
| `_ _ _ _` | `_ _ ▯ _` | He does [whack] a fly while he [soaks in alum, salts, egg yolk, and flour] the pigskins. |
| `_ _ ▯ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ _ _` | Does karma choose the [more evil] man to [again experience] his unhappiness? |
| `_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _` | `▯ _ _ _ _ _ _ _` | The [awarder] chose the [re-sketcher] of classic landscape pieces. |
| `_ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ _ _` | Horses [hurriedly swalllow] the water when the [stopper] was removed. |
| `_ _ _ ▯` | `_ ▯ ▯ _` | She [soaks] the cloth as they [slowly boil] the ingredients. |
| `_ _ _ ▯` | `_ ▯ _ _` | She's in a [sulk] because I dented the [metal canisters]. |
| `_ _ _ _ _` | `_ _ ▯ _ _` | We learned about [a kidney enzyme] and heard the word [nine in the NATO alphabet] on the radio. |
| `_ _ _ _ ▯` | `_ _ _ _ _` | The sailfish entered the [waters far from the surface] with [swiftness]. |
| `_ ▯ _ _ _ _` | `_ _ ▯ _ _ ▯` | I [compensated] my son for changing his brother's dirty [absorbent infant garment]. |
| `_ _ ▯` | `_ _ _` | The tank of [common car fuel] will [droop from pressure] when it is full. |

### Section 7 of 8

| -------- Word 1 -------- | -------- Word 2 -------- | Sentence Using Both Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _` | **`_ H _ _ [_ _ _ _ _] _ F [_ _ _ _ _ _ _ C _ _].`** |
| `_ ▯ _` | `_ _ _` | I made a [short animation file] of me pruning a [ficus] tree. |
| `_ ▯ _` | `_ _ _` | Even a [small amount] is [not good]. |
| `_ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ ▯` | [Brown ruminant mammals] avoid the [mass of tall grasses that grow in wet areas]. |
| `_ _ ▯ _ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ _ _ _` | The [re-experiencer] of a bad experience with planes was the movie's only [denouncer]. |
| `_ _ _ _` | `_ _ ▯ _` | The plastic [hoop] floated in the [small body of water]. |
| `_ ▯ _` | `_ _ ▯` | His fishing style was to [dib] while sitting on a [thin, flat cushion]. |
| `▯ _ _ _ _ _` | `_ _ ▯ _ ▯ _` | The [spies] ate with [handled, shallow bowls]. |
| `_ _ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ ▯ _` | The store-bought [seasoned Italian pasta sauces] all contained added [crystalline sucrose]. |
| `_ _ _ ▯` | `_ _ ▯ _` | My [buddies] wanted to [open-handedly strike] the attendant. |
| `▯ _ _` | `_ _ _` | The dog slept in the [front part of the lower trunk and thighs] of my seated [friend]. |
| `_ _ _ _` | `▯ _ _ _` | He [moved through the water] away from the [jaws] of the lion and the crocodile. |
| `_ ▯ _` | `_ _ _` | She will [apply surface pressure] to the acorn to remove its [rough envelope]. |
| `_ _ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _` | He was [highly self-satisfied] that his [tissues surrounding the necks of his teeth] were healthy. |
| `▯ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _` | The [chumps] overpaid for the [health clubs]. |

### Section 8 of 8

| -------- Word 1 -------- | -------- Word 2 -------- | Sentence Using Both Words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ _ _ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ _ _` | **`_ _ _ _ _ H _ [_ _ _ _ C H _ _] _ _ _ H _ [_ _ _ _ _ Y] _ _ _ _ _ _.`** |
| `_ _ ▯ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ _ _` | He [fished with a net that hangs vertically in the water] but [disavows] keeping any fish. |
| `▯ ▯ _ _ ▯` | `_ ▯ _ _ _` | The witch had [skin growths] and a broom made with [threshed grain stalks]. |
| `_ ▯ _ _ _` | `▯ _ _ _ _` | He [removes the skin of] the orange as we [slumber]. |
| `_ _ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ ▯` | She [firmly links] her hands after smelling the skunk's [stench]. |
| `_ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ _ ▯` | The ocean might [abound] with sharks, but I hope I never [come into contact with] one. |
| `▯ ▯ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _` | Being hit by [Cupid]'s arrow shouldn't make one [physically tender from injury]. |
| `_ _ _ ▯ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ _ _ _ _` | He [gave definite content and form to] self-confidence, being a [worshipper] of individualism. |
| `_ _ _ _` | `▯ _ _ _` | He [expectorated saliva] on the beer [spigots]. |
| `_ _ _ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ _ _ _ _` | The [watchman] wants to [revise] part of the blueprint. |
| `_ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ ▯` | The [insectivorous flying mammals] take a [turn] at catching bugs. |
| `_ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ _ _` | [Cease] dropping the clay [plant containers]. |
| `_ _ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _` | She had a [blunt] nose and two [hair twists wrapped around themselves]. |
| `▯ _ _ _` | `_ ▯ _ _` | The spice on these [hard-shelled dry fruits with separable rinds] will [surprise] you. |
| `▯ _ ▯ _ _` | `▯ _ _ _ _` | He [combines] all his resources to buy the [single-masted, fore-and-aft-rigged sailboat]. |
| `_ _ _ _` | `▯ _ _ _` | This [area] of the video game has a tricky [entanglement]. |
| `_ _ _ _ ▯ _` | `_ _ _ _ _ _` | The [hidden rifleman] [re-fastens] the badge on his vest. |
| `_ _ _ _` | `_ _ _ ▯` | There were two [knocks] at the door and they began to [box]. |

Comment: @lukasrotter Thank you so much for editing that. I now see that the rectangles that represent outlined letter spaces look bad (super thin horizontally) on mobile, but great on my laptop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We are looking for

> pairs of words that are one another's reverses. Having found them, the highlighted letters from each section form a sentence shown at the start of the section which clues another reversal-pair, one of which goes into the sentence.

Part I, section 1:

> These are pairs of words that are one another's reverses. DIM/MID; REKNITS/STINKER; WOLFER/REFLOW; YAP/PAY; TUMS/SMUT; ROT/TOR; SHE/EHS; PREP/PERP. The highlighted letters say I IDENTIFY AS MOTHER, again cluing a reversal-pair AM/MA. First word for Part I is AM.

Part I, section 2:

> PUPILS/SLIPUP; TANG/GNAT; LOOTER/RETOOL; EEL/LEE; YAPS/SPAY; STIRPS/SPRITS; KNAPS/SPANK; LIVE/EVIL; WAY/YAW; USING TROLLEYS IS SAVVY; TRAMS/SMART. First word for Part I is SMART.

Part I, section 3:

> SHOO/OOHS; LACED/DECAL; GATEMAN/NAMETAG; LAUD/DUAL; GEL/LEG; PACER/RECAP; TEED/DEET; HE/EH; BAT/TAB; OH/HO. SHE CLEANED ALL EXCEPT THE BATH; TUB/BUT. Third word for Part I is BUT.

Part I, section 4:

> TIME/EMIT; TAG/GAT; RESAT/TASER; TAR/RAT; FACED/DECAF; HEM/MEH; YO/OY; TUBER/REBUT; GOD/DOG; SUB/BUS; ROOM/MOOR; NET/TEN. I MIGHT EAT A STARCHY TUBEROUS ROOT; MAY/YAM. Fourth word for Part I is MAY.

Part I, section 5:

> BRO/ORB; TATS/STAT; BOON/NOOB; TUG/GUT; UM/MU; SWAY/YAWS; TILER/RELIT; FLOG/GOLF; STRAP/PARTS; KEEL/LEEK. I BOAST ABOUT MY STYLE OF APPAREL; BRAG/GARB. Fifth word for Part I is BRAG.

Part I, section 6:

> GALS/SLAG; FLOW/WOLF; NAMER/REMAN; NOD/DON; FIRES/SERIF; DIALER/RELAID; BUD/DUB; DENIM/MINED. A SLOW WOMAN DOES FALL BEHIND; GAL/LAG. Sixth word for Part I is GAL.

Part I, section 7:

> NONET/TENON; NEVES/SEVEN; DEUS/SUED; DOOM/MOOD; NIP/PIN; ARRET/TERRA; SLEETS/STEELS; TIPS/SPIT. ONE VENUE DOMINATES THE LIST. SPOT/TOPS. Seventh word for Part I is SPOT.

Part I, section 8:

> PAT/TAPS; HOOP/POOH; EDIT/TIDE; ROOD/DOOR; REVEL/LEVER; DRAY/YARD; PANS/SNAP; TUBED/DEBUT; RAM/MAR; TINKER/REKNIT. THE TROLLEY PASSED BY A MARKET. TRAM/MART. Eighth word for Part I is MART.

Putting Part I together, the sentence we get is:

> **I AM SMART BUT MAY BRAG TO A GAL I SPOT AT THE MART**.

Part II, section 1:

> RATS/STAR; DEMIT/TIMED; RANK/KNAR; SPIDER/REDIPS; KEEP/PEEK; OGRE/ERGO; RAW/WAR; RAIL/LIAR; SPOTS/STOPS; NORI/IRON; PETS/STEP; SERACS/SCARES; NEW/WEN. A TIMEKEEPER WILL POSTPONE THE RACE. TIMER/REMIT. First word is TIMER.

Part II, section 2:

> LAID/DIAL; GUM/MUG; SNAPS/SPANS; NOT/TON; PAN/NAP; REPEL/LEPER; TOPER/REPOT; GAR/RAG; DENIER/REINED; SUNG/GNUS; TORT/TROT; NIT/TIN; SON/NOS. I AM NOT AN EXPERT REGARDING NUTRITION; NO/ON. Second word is ON.

Part II, section 3:

> STOPER/REPOTS; REVILED/DELIVER; NAPS/SPAN; NAB/BAN; LOOPS/SPOOL; KNOB/BONK; DEVIL/LIVED; KEELS/SLEEK; SWAP/PAWS; SCRAM/MARCS; TOP/POT; SPOOLS/SLOOPS; SPIN/NIPS. THE SNOB LIKES CARTOONS; SNOOT/TOONS. Third word is SNOOT.

Part II, section 4:

> DAM/MAD; BUTS/STUB; TINK/KNIT; GATS/STAG; TOOL/LOOT; GUNS/SNUG; WED/DEW; OAT/TAO; GAB/BAG; ER/RE; PEES/SEEP; BARD/DRAB; SPRAT/TARPS. MY CUTTING TOOL USED TO BE SHARP; SAW/WAS. Fourth word is WAS.

Part II, section 5:

> PIT/TIP; RECAPS/SPACER; REFED/DEFER; MAPS/SPAM; SNIP/PINS; SPAZ/ZAPS; SEED/DEES; WE/EW; DEETS/STEED; ARE/ERA; LAGER/REGAL; RAP/PAR; TOTS/STOT. THE CHEF EMPHASIZED SWEET TREATS; STRESSED/DESSERTS.  Fifth word is STRESSED.

Part II, section 6:

> PEED/DEEP; DRAW/WARD; LOOTS/STOOL; SWAT/TAWS; EVILER/RELIVE; REWARDER/REDRAWER; GULP/PLUG; WETS/STEW; SNIT/TINS; RENIN/NINER; DEEPS/SPEED; REPAID/DIAPER; GAS/SAG. ED TWIRLS THE TIN SHEARS; SPINS/SNIPS; sixth word is SNIPS.

Part II, section 7:

> GIF/FIG; DAB/BAD; DEER/REED; RELIVER/REVILER; LOOP/POOL; DAP/PAD; SNOOPS/SPOONS; RAGUS/SUGAR; PALS/SLAP; LAP/PAL; SWAM/MAWS; RUB/BUR; SMUG/GUMS; SAPS/SPAS. I HAD LOADS OF NASAL MUCUS; TONS/SNOT. Seventh word is TONS.

Part II, section 8:

> SEINED/DENIES; WARTS/STRAW; PEELS/SLEEP; KNITS/STINK; TEEM/MEET; EROS/SORE; REIFIED/DEIFIER; SPAT/TAPS; BATS/STAB; STOP/POTS; SNUB/BUNS; NUTS/STUN; POOLS/SLOOP; PART/TRAP; SNIPER/REPINS; RAPS/SPAR. I WAS THE SKETCHER OF THE BOUNTY POSTER. DRAWER/REWARD. Last word for Part II is REWARD.

Sentence from part II:

> **WITH THE TIMER ON, THE SNOOT WAS STRESSED, BUT NOW HE SNIPS TONS OF TOPS FOR THE REWARD**.

Note on this last:

> Either he snips tons of tops (of e.g. cereal packets, to send off for a prize), or else he spins tons of tops (meaning toys that spin on their axis). I went with the first option, but in comments JLee has indicated that he had the second in mind.

A few comments on the puzzle, which JLee should read if and only if he would be glad of constructive criticism:

> I'm afraid I really didn't enjoy solving this very much; it was too much of a slog. (But once I'd started I thought I should finish.) It often felt as if I was spending more time and mental effort on bookkeeping -- copying letters from one place to another, finding my place again after doing so, etc. -- than on actual solving. Also, though this might have been quite difficult to avoid, it seemed as if there were too many things where the answer was pretty much in the question. "Put laces in" -> LACED, "more evil" -> EVILER, "again places in pots" -> REPOTS (paired with "stope drillman" -> STOPER, same issue), etc. To me this feels like poor style. And I was a bit disappointed that there wasn't some clever final step using both answers somehow; without that, having two sentences just amounted to setting two basically-identical independent puzzles rather than one, and I didn't find the experience of solving so pleasurable that I was glad to have twice as much work :-).

Credit where due:

> When solving I left some things undone and then returned to them later. I missed a few. My apologies for this, and thanks to @MOehm who kindly provided solutions in the comments so I didn't have to figure them out. If you like this answer, then you should randomly and with smallish probability go and upvote one of MOehm's questions or answers :-).

Comment: Thx for the feedback. I worked on this for over 3 weeks. I started with about 900 words and one by one reduced the list to somewhat common words, in most cases. I ended up with 200 words. I almost made this into 2 or more puzzles, but I decided not to because so many of these were so easy that a shorter version may be too trivial, and because many people dislike it when the same type of puzzle is posted around the same time. Since these 200 are exhaustive, I figured I'd make it big and get'em all. Sorry you didn't enjoy it. Back in the day that would have really bothered me, but these days...

Comment: I'm just focused much more on the fact that **I** really had fun making this puzzle! As always, thx for your honesty.  I returned the favor.

Comment: The missing three are rot13(SNAPS/SPANS; REVILED/DELIVER; LOOPS/SPOOL). I concur with the gist of Gareth's criticism. I can see how you had fun creating this puzzle, but rot13(V svaq gur furre fvmr n ovg birejuryzvat. V fnj gur cnggrea naq fbyirq gur svefg sbhe frpgvbaf. Gur nzbhag bs cnvef nyfb znxrf gurz n ovg ercrgvgvir. Znal ner ba gur ER.../...RE be QR.../...RQ cnggreaf. Naq jr unir r.t. FANCF/FCNAF naq va gur arkg frpgvba, ANCF/FCNA). But thanks for making the puzzle. I liked the core mechanic.

Comment: @MOehm thx for the feedback

Comment: Oops, my apologies; I thought I'd gone through and fixed up all the missing pairs, but apparently not. (I don't mean that I solved them all and just hadn't written them in, I mean I thought I'd gone back and solved everything but evidently I hadn't.) Thanks to @MOehm; I'm about to edit those answers in and credit him. As for the incorrect word, I claim both the one I gave and its pair are possible and will explain why in an answer-edit :-).

Comment: Missing answers now edited in, along with explanation for why the "incorrect" word in the second sentence is as reasonable an answer as its partner.

Comment: +1 and the check mark. Thx for adding that in.